# Python dataframe - compare rows between two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe (let's call it A) that looks like:

```
         Date    Open    High     Low   Close  Adj Close   Volume
0  2010-01-04  9.1825  9.2350  9.0875  9.1025     9.1025  1172000
1  2010-01-05  9.1025  9.1350  9.0550  9.1000     9.1000   658000
2  2010-01-06  9.0750  9.1150  9.0450  9.0625     9.0625   617600
3  2010-01-07  9.0250  9.0600  8.9425  9.0100     9.0100   913600
4  2010-01-08  8.9750  9.0375  8.9250  9.0375     9.0375  1271200
```

and I am calculating the total days for which the close in day t was greater than the close of day t-1:

```
total_positive_days = (asset.Close > asset.Close.shift(1)).sum()
```

I have another dataframe (called sp_500) for which I want to calculate the total number of days for which the return of day t for A (Close A t - Close A t-1)/Close A t-1 is greater than the return of sp_500 (Close sp_500 t - Close sp_500 t-1)/Close sp_500 t-1

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set index on the date then create new columns in you dataframes

```
A['return'] = A.close - A.close.shift(1) / A.close.shift(1)
sp_500['return'] = sp_500.close - sp_500.close.shift(1) / sp_500.close.shift(1)
```

then merge based on Date